# Programmatically set a $form_state value for user reference

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm trying to programmatically create nodes through form submit in Drupal 8 (because I need to validate the submitted values) in this way.

```
try {
  $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node')
    ->create(array('type' => 'my_bundle_id'));

  $node->set('my_field', 'my_value');

  $node_form_object = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getFormObject('node', 'default')
    ->setEntity($node);

  $form_state = new FormState();
  $form_state->setValue('my_field', $node->get('my_field')->getValue());
  $form_state->setValue('op', $this->t('Save'));
  \Drupal::formBuilder()->submitForm($node_form_object, $form_state);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  Drupal::messenger()->addError($e->getMessage());
}
```

Before setting any `$form_state` value, I'm evaluating the field type case (datetime, created and so on) to pass a right value getting it from `$node`.

Everything works correctly, except in case of a field referencing existing users which is passed to `$form_state` as follows.

```
$form_state->setValue('user_ref_field', array (
  0 =>  array (
    'target_id' => '1', // right uid of user
  ),
 )
);
```

Same happens with fields referencing taxonomy terms unless in default node form mode I don't set client hierarchical select (coming from a third-party module) as widget, while in case of user reference (with any widget type set in node default form) I get a *There are no entities matching '1'* (my user ID).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` you're putting a number inside quotes; thus, making it a string rather than integer. Should be `'target_id' => 1,`

Comment: I didn't try a number instead of string because inside values of a $form_state of a node submitted through a normal node form (not programatically) it is a string not a number. I had this doubt while writing code in my question. I will give it a try anyway. Thanks

Comment: Despite my previous comment, it seems weird to me, but it works, tomorrow i will analize it again. Thank you again @NoSssweat